# Product database with multiple attributes and not lots of database tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have started to create a database for floor-ing products and I am asking question here because I have failed to find a schema design / template that allows the products to have "attributes" such as colour, material, size, price type such as per metre and so on, and my initial design I ended up with database tables for each of the above attributes, which I know can't be the best or even right way to do it.

Is there a way to achieve this without lots of tables?  I suspect it can maybe be done with one or two tables but I am unable to think of the relationships hence my failed search for a design or template.

Barry

Comment: Is there a set number of attributes per product, or will there be a varying number of attributes?

Comment: Ideally varying, mainly i guess due to the different types of floor-ing.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is to keep the attributes in separate columns in the `products` table.  If a particular product doesn't have an attribute, then the value would be `NULL`.

Sometimes this approach is not sufficient, often for one of two reasons:

- There are lots of attributes and they fall into different groupings.
- You need to add new attributes on demand.

In this case, you basically have two choices:

- Store the attributes in an entity-attribute-value table (EAV).  This basically has three columns, the product, the attribute name, and the value.  This can be convenient and flexible, but one downside is that the "value" column has only one type in a SQL table.
- Store the attributes using a "flexible" storage mechanism, such as JSON or XML.

I sometimes use a hybrid approach, where I have a `products` table with the main attributes.  Then there is a JSON column for more flexible/specific attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would have varying numbers of attributes, I would do a table for the product and another for the attributes with a many-to-one relationship [one product has many attributes].

```
ProductId,
ProductName,
ProductDescription,
etc
```

```
AttributeId,
ProductId,
AttributeName,
AttributeValue,
etc
```